# Ionic 4 navigate in lifecycle event, prevent showing page on reload

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router, ionic4

I have a page which should not load unless the user is logged in (account details). However, if the user goes to that direct URL, I'd prefer to direct him to the login page. Currently I'm doing this:

```
ionViewWillEnter() { 
  if (notLoggedIn()){
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/tabs/(account:account/login)');
    console.log('No user defined when at registration page, redirecting');
    }
  }
```

I get the console to log, but the page does not navigate to the proper page (The URL changes, but the old page shows).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the Ionic lifecycle events are not firing in Ionic 4, I think due to switching to Angular Routing instead of the Ionic routing. Particularly in the NavController documentation it shows ionViewCanEnter working with a navCtrl.push method, not the new way which is the navCtrl.navigateRoot or forwards/backwards (which is what I first tried before what's typed above).

So, to fix it, I went with normal Angular routing lifecycle guards, but stuck with the Ionic NavController to navigate. I created a new lifecycle guard as shown:

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {

    if (this.userService.isLoggedIn()) { return true; }
    this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/tabs/(account:account/login)');
    return false;

  }
```

Works great.

Good documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/router) for anyone learning Ionic and Angular together